# REST Best practise for filtering and knowing the result is singular: List or single?

Tags: rest

Variety of REST practises suggest (i.e. [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design), [2](https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/), [3](https://medium.com/hashmapinc/rest-good-practices-for-api-design-881439796dc9)) to use plurals in your endpoints and the result is always a list of objects, unless it's filtered by a specific value, such as `/users/123` Query parameters are used to filter the list, but still result in a list, nevertheless. I want to know if my case should 'abandon' those best practices.

*Let's use cars for my example below.*
I've got a database full of cars and each one has a BuildNumber ("Id"), but also a model and build year which combination is unique. If I then query for `/cars/` and search for a specific model and year, for example `/cars?model=golf&year=2018` I know, according to my previous sentence, my retrieve will always contain a single object, never multiple. My result, however, will still be a list, containing just one object, nevertheless.

In such case, what will be the best practise as the above would mean the object have to be extracted from the list, even though a single object could've been returned instead.

1. Stick to best practises and export a list
2. Make a second endpoind `/car/` and use the query parameters `?model=golf&year=2018`, which are primarily used for filtering in a list, and have the result be a single object, as the singular endpoint states

---

The reason that I'm asking this is simply for the cleanness of the action: I'm 100% sure my GET request will result in single object, but still have to perform actions to extract it from the list. These steps should've been unnecessary. Aside of that, In my case I don't know the unique identifier, so `cars/123` for retrieving a specific car isn't an option. I know, however,  filters that will result in one object and one specific object altogether. The additional steps simply feel redundant.

---

1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design
2: https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/
3: https://medium.com/hashmapinc/rest-good-practices-for-api-design-881439796dc9

Answer (score 1):

As you've specifically asked for best practices in regards to REST:

REST doesn't care how you specify your URIs or that semantically meaningful tokens are used inside the URI at all. Further, a client should [never expect a certain URI to return a certain type](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) but instead rely on content-type negotiation to tell the server all of the capabilities the client supports.

You should furthermore not think of REST in terms of object orientation but more in terms of [affordance and statemachines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1222&v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=13m37s) where a client get served every information needed in order to make an educated decision on what to do next.

The best sample to give here is probably to take a close look at the Web and how it's done for HTML pages. How can you filter for a specific car and how it will be presented to you? The same concepts that are used in the Web also apply to REST as both use the same interaction model. In regards to your car sample, the API should initially return some control-structures that teach a client how a request needs to be formed and what options could be filtered for. In HTML this is done via forms. For non-HTML based REST APIs dedicated media-types should be defined that translate the same approach to non-HTML structures. On sending the request to the server, your client would include all of the supported media-types it supports in an `Accept` HTTP header, which informs the server about the capabilities of the client. Media-types are just human-readable specification on how to process payloads of such types. Such specifications [may include hints on type information a link relation might return](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-3.4). In order to gain wide-usage of media-types they should be defined as generic as possible. Instead of defining a media-type specific for a car, which is possible, it probably would be more convenient to use an existing or define a new general data-container format (similar to HTML).

All of the steps mentioned here should help you to design and implement an API that is free to evolve without having to risk to break clients, that furthermore is also scalable and minimizes interoperability concerns.

Unfortunately your question targets something totally different IMO, something more related to RPC. You basically invoke a generic method via HTTP on an endpoint, similar like SOAP, RMI or CORBA work. Whether you respect the semantics of HTTP operations or not is only of sub-interest here. Even if you'd reached level 3 of the [Richardson Maturity Model (RMM)](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) it does not mean that you are compliant to REST. Your client might still break if the server changes anything within the response. The RMM further doesn't even consider media-types at all, hence I consider it as rather useless.

However, regardless if you use a (true) REST or RPC/CRUD client, if retrieving single items is your preference instead of feeding them into a collection you should consider to include the URI of the items of interest instead of its data directly into the collection, as Evert also has suggested. While most people seem to be concerned on server performance and round-trip-times, it actually is very elegant in terms of caching. Further certain link-relation names such as [`prefetch`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) may inform the client that it may fetch the targets payload early as it is highly possible that it's content will be requested next. Through caching a request might not even have to be triggered or sent to the server for processing, which is probably the best performance gain you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you use query like cars/where... - use CARS

2) If you whant CAR - make method GetCarById

Comment: You suggest to stick to the list, since I'm using query parameters? I'm not filtering by ID, because I don't know this value; Yet I know my filters will result in a single object.

Comment: It's not about you now result or not, its about convention of result set. If result set CAN return array - its always CARS

Answer (score 0):

You might not get a perfect answer to this, because all are going to be a bit subjective and often in a different way.

My general thought about this is that every item in my system will have its own unique url, for example `/cars/1234`. That case is always singular.

But this specific item might appear as a member in collections and search results. When `/cars/1234` apears in these, they will always appear as a list with 1 item (or 0 or more depending on the query).

I feel that this is ultimately the most predictable.

In my case though, if a car appears as a member of a search or colletion, it's 'true url' will still be displayed.